# How to transfer my iPhone connection to my laptop via USB?

Tags: windows-vista, iphone, internet, connection

I have an iPhone with 3g connection and I want to transfer it to my PC laptop via USB cable, and not WiFi.

Is there any solution or tool for that?

Note: I'm running Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called iPhone USB tethering:
"Connect your iPhone to your computer via USB and select the iPhone USB network service as your network connection. All the necessary software is automatically installed using iTunes."

http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-3gs/tethering.html

Answer (score 1):

Tethering doesn't work on AT&T though.
So unless you are willing to jailbreak your iPhone (voiding the warranty and making yourself vulnerable to malicious software) you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone IS jailbroken, then there is a walkthrough [here](http://osxgoodies.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/simple-iphone-3-x-tethering/) that will take you through the process.